# How do I make a textfield uneditable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this textfield that I want to always have this value:

```
<%= text_field_tag :quantity, "1", class: "uneditable-input" %>
```

i.e. I don't want the user to be able to change the quantity value to anything other than 1.

I tried adding `disabled: true` and that worked to grey out the field, but it also disabled it - changing the behavior of the form (i.e. the form was submitted without a quantity value).

All I want to do is to force every person that submits this form to be able to see the Quantity of 1 - and not be able to change it - and have the system process quantity of 1.

How do I do that?

Comment: whatever you do client side, you have to handle code properly server side: it's always possible to edit html directly even if an input is disabled.

Comment: Hrmm... @apneadiving good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this
 `<%= text_field_tag :quantity, "1", class: "uneditable-input", :readonly => true %>`
or if you want to disable it you can do it this way

`<%= text_field_tag :quantity, "1", class: "uneditable-input", :disabled => true  %>`

Answer (score 4):

Just try:

```
<%= text_field_tag :quantity,:readonly => true%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the text field value to 1 server side, leaving `disabled: true` client side.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= text_field_tag :quantity, nil, {value: "1", disabled: true} %>
```

Output:

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" value="1">
```